# Stack Overflow profile page doesn't show reputation graph on mobile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-graph, responsive-design

I couldn't help noticing that, on [my Stack Overflow profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1322396/ben-the-coder), the reputation graph in the summary section doesn't show on mobile or portrait devices.  I feel that there's easily space to fit the graph on the mobile page.

I have an idea on how to do this:

> You could add a settings option to turn on the graph on all devices.  I understand that this would be a lot of work for SO (I'm a website developer myself), but that (at least for me) it would be very worth it.

I noticed that when my device is turned into landscape mode (and the screen is wide enough), the graph shows.

To be clear, I'm not talking about the `Reputation > Graph tab`, I'm talking about the 4-year reputation graph shown on the summary tab:

> [image: Desktop vs. Mobile]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1665/discussion-on-question-by-ben-the-coder-stack-overflow-profile-page-doesnt-show); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.